# JWT Token Expired issue when using Twilio JS Client API

Tags: javascript, python, django, twilio

I'm creating a webb application where one can click on a number and dial from the browser.

I'm using the [Twilio JS Client API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/twilio-js) and a Django back end to generate capability tokens. I'm using this [Python Helper Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install).

Everything seems to be working just fine but as soon as I'm trying to make a call I get a error on my client:

```
Uncaught Twilio.Exception: 31205: [object Object] twilio.min.js:45

WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

Error 31205 is a JWT token expired error which is strange as the token has had a lifetime of 1 minute at most when I click-to-dial.

This is my view method in Django which generates a nice capability token:

```
def dialer(req, phone_number):
    capability = TwilioCapability(settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
                                  settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    # allow outgoing voice
    capability.allow_client_outgoing(settings.TWILIO_APP_SID)
    profile = user_models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=req.user)
    v = {'capability_token': capability.generate(expires=600),
         'phone_number': phone_number, 'user': req.user, 
         'caller_id': profile.user_phone}
    return shortcuts.render_to_response('dialer.html', v)
```

And this is the JavaScript in my dialer.html:

```
Twilio.Device.setup('{{capability_token}}'); 
Twilio.Device.ready( function(device) {
   console.log('Device ready...');
}); 
Twilio.Device.connect({
   CallerId:'{{caller_id}}',
   PhoneNumber: '{{phone_number}}'
});
$('#hang-up').click( function() {
   Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
});
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error? The Twilio documentation says that the capability_token has a lifetime of one hour as default.

Thanks!

PS. I made the exact same application using Node.js as back end and that works great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED IT!

So there isn't any issues with code. The problem was my Virtual Machine that had the wrong date/time settings.

So, make sure that is correct when your trying to retrieve capability tokens from Twilio :)

Comment: thansks , it helps me , i west my whole day for this , and finally your suggestion is help , i set my date and time correct and it's work :)

Comment: Good to hear! @chiragpatel

Comment: This was my problem with the Twilio token too. Laravel Homestead has a notorious clock slip problem. https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/799#issuecomment-392079462